# How to change JDBC Encoding to support French accent characters

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, encoding, character-encoding

im having a problem with fetching data from **Mysql 5.1** using **JDBC**(mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar).

my insert into statement goes like this:

```
    INSERT INTO Categories  VALUES ('01','Matières premières');
```

and the output from **Netbeans** terminal  and Swing Interfaces goes like this :

```
    MatiŠres premiŠres
```

i think that I need to specify the encoding parameters.

can you please help.

p.s: the OS is Windows 7 French.

this is my url to the database in class connection :

```
    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://X.X.X.X:XXXX/XXXX?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8","XXXX","XXXX");
```

Comment: The biggest problem is probably not in JDBC but in the database. What's the encoding of your table and connection ? I suggest you set them as "utf8-general-ci".

Comment: i dunno how to set the jdbc to support French accent characters, would mind to help with a code snippet, thank you sire.

Comment: We're talking about the database, not jdbc. You usually set the collation of the tables when creating it (you can change it with any admin tool), and you may change as well the collation used for connections with this tool.

Comment: i don't think so, the select statement on the Mysql terminal gives correct data encoding. mysql charset is "latin2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two solutions :

- the sanest one : set your tables to use as collation "utf8-general-ci" and set mysql to use the same collation for connections. So you won't have any problem and you won't need to specify anything when connecting using jdbc.
- another one, barely acceptable now but possible : determine what's the collation of your tables and use it to configure your connection in JDBC as described here : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-charsets.html . But you **must** know what's the encoding of your tables (as you don't know it  and if you're in France it may be Latin1).

To determine or change the encoding of your tables you may use any mysql admin tool. Be sure to be coherent for the tables and connection.

Comment: *Collation* is irrelevant, except insofar as MySQL (sensibly) requires collations to be applicable to the relevant string's *character set/encoding* (which, I think, is what you meant).  Muddling the two just leads to more confusion (you even referred to `utf8_general_ci`--note underscores, not hyphens--as an *encoding* in [your comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12300813/how-to-change-jdbc-encoding-to-support-french-accent-characters#comment16503095_12300813) above).

Comment: @eggyal Can you make a clearer answer ? I'll be happy to delete mine if yours is less confusing.

Comment: please help, the answers provided are too vague.

Answer (score 0):

you have to set encoding to ISO-8859-1 with System.setProperty("file.encoding", "ISO-8859-1")